# Nested ambiguously typed methods

Tags: haskell

Say I have a class

```
class T where
    tag1 :: String
    tag2 :: String
```

With ambiguous types enabled, I could specify each of them in an instance:

```
instance T A where
    tag1 = "tag1"
    tag2 = "tag2"
```

If I want to make `tag2` append something to `tag1`, I can define

```
instance T A where 
    tag1 = "tag1"
    tag2 = tag1 @A ++ " suffix"
```

This works great, but if I want `tag2` to always append `suffix` to each `tag1`, I seem to have to specify the ambiguous call for each instance.

I understand the need for this, as `tag1` from any instance would work for each call. However, is there any trick within haskell for me to specify it once only?

Something like

```
tag2 :: T a => String
tag2 = tag1 @a ++ " suffix"
```

Comment: As it stands, your code does not compile since the class has no parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code currently does not compile since the type class has no type parameters, so I'm going to assume your code is actually (assuming `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is enabled)

```
class T a where
    tag1 :: String
    tag2 :: String
```

Now you can provide a default implementation for `tag2`:

```
class T a where
    tag1 :: String
    tag2 :: String
    tag2 = "tag2"
```

But this does not meet the requirement of adding the suffix to `tag1`.
We could try this(assuming `TypeApplications` is enabled):

```
class T a where
    tag1 :: String
    tag2 :: String
    tag2 = tag1 @a ++ "suffix"
```

Now this *won't* compile, and the compilation error will be

```
error: Not in scope: type variable `a'
```

and rightfully so, the type `a` isn't defined anywhere. However, we want to refer to the `a` in the head of the class, for this we need the language extension [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#lexically-scoped-type-variables), and with that the code will compile and you'll get the results you expect (I suggest reading up the linked documentation)

Here's a full program that demonstrates the usage:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

class T a where
  tag1 :: String
  tag2 :: String
  tag2 = tag1 @a ++ " suffix"

data A = A
data B = B

instance T A where
  tag1 = "tagA"

instance T B where
  tag1 = "tagB"
  tag2 = "tagB overriden"

main = do
  putStrLn $ tag1 @A
  putStrLn $ tag2 @A
  putStrLn $ tag1 @B
  putStrLn $ tag2 @B
```

And the output is:

```
> ./foo
tagA
tagA suffix
tagB
tagB overriden
```

Comment: I did indeed make a mistake when typing it out. Both answers were great, but I will accept yours as I believe you answered first. I was not aware of the language flag

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do exactly this - `tag1 @a`, but you need to make two modifications: enable `ScopedTypeVariables` and add an explicit `forall`, like this:

```
tag2 :: forall a. T a => String 
tag2 = tag1 @a ++ " suffix"
```

The explicit `forall` is what creates a scope for the type variable `a`, making it accessible in the whole body of `tag2`. Without it (i.e. by the standard Haskell 2010 rules) the type variable is scoped only to the type signature and is inaccessible in the body.

If you'd like to have `tag2` as a class method, rather than a standalone function, you can add a default implementation for it like this:

```
class T a where
    tag1 :: String

    tag2 :: String
    tag2 = tag1 @a ++ " suffix"
```

In this case you don't need to provide an explicit `forall`. Instead, the scope of the type variable will be the whole class instance. But you still need `ScopedTypeVariables`, otherwise there will be no scope at all.